# What exactly qualifies as a declaration of an identifier?

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

I am trying to construct some code such that it takes a user's input, runs one loop, takes the end value of that loop, and then runs that value through a second loop (I am also adding to a counter each time a loop runs and printfing it at the end), this was my attempt at coding this:

```
{
    float input = get_float("%s", "Input: ");
    float w = input * 100;
    {
    int c = 0;
    for (int q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25)
        {
        c++;
        }
    for (int d = q; d > 9; d = d - 10)
        {
        c++;
        }
    printf("%i", c);
    }
}
```

The error I receive is `error: use of undeclared identifier 'q'`. I thought that, since it was used earlier in the code, it wouldn't be a problem to identify it later on, though obviously that's not true. Any advice on either now to properly declare 'q' would be appreciated- or perhaps my entire approach is simply misguided?

Comment: Variables/identifiers have their *scope*. `q` is in the scope of the `for` loop block it was declared in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `q` in the first loop it exists only inside this one loop as a local variable

Declaring the variable outside the `for` scope will leave it accessible on the second loop

````
{
    float input = get_float("%s", "Input: ");
    float w = input * 100;
    {
    int c = 0;
    int q;
    for (q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25)
        {
        c++;
        }
    for (int d = q; d > 9; d = d - 10)
        {
        c++;
        }
    printf("%i", c);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `q` declared in the loop is only available in the loop. You should declare it before the loop to make it available after the loop.

```
{
    float input = get_float("%s", "Input: ");
    float w = input * 100;
    {
    int c = 0;
    int q; // declare q before the loop
    for (q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25) // no declaration of q here
        {
        c++;
        }
    for (int d = q; d > 9; d = d - 10)
        {
        c++;
        }
    printf("%i", c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (int q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25)` <- q is ok in this block

`for (int d = q; d > 9; d = d - 10)` <- q doesn't exist within this block

Add `int q;` below `int c = 0;` and modify `for (int q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25)` to `for (q = w; q > 24; q = q - 25)`

Comment: Only adding `int q;` will leave it uninitialized and cause trouble in the second `for` loop. `int` of `int q = w;` should be removed after adding that.

Comment: @MikeCAT can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear in my response. I'll edit it so that it is in line with your response above.